# I need advice regarding my speeding ticket issued in New York

Tags: legal, driving, driving-licenses, new-york-state

Just recently, my friends (tourists) and I booked a rental car just for a day trip in New York. Unfortunately, we got caught by a cop for speeding. I showed my foreign driver's license to a cop and my passport. I don't have a driver's license issued by the DMV as I'm still new here in the US (H4 VISA). My friends are tourists and they were in New York for a 2-day visit.

My question is, if I plead guilty, I know they will fine me, but would it somewhat create an impact on my driver's license application if I decided to get a driver's license in the future?

Second question, is the point system still be applicable to me even though I don't have a driver's license yet?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better suited for law stackexchange, or perhaps an attorney you hire to advise you.

Comment: [law.se] site is here.

Comment: the USA has so many bad drivers who speed all the time that it's impossible they deny driver's licenses based on having speeding tickets

Comment: @user253751 That's not quite incorrect. Certainly there are lots of drivers who speed. Most states, however, assess "points" against driver's licenses when tickets are issued or sustained in court. If a licensed driver gets too many points, the state DMV won't renew their license when it expires.